# mongoose/express Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined

Tags: express, mongoose

Following a tutorial on udemy and came across this error. "Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined". Ive had this problem before but it was because i forgot to authenticate the json web token. This time it is authenticated and the code was check letter for letter and is exactly the same. We all know that 100% of code tutorials are outdated and missing info.

Auth was checked and verified. fields were checked and verified. the one area i see is that "experience" doesn't have a "constructor" ?

```
router.put(
    '/experience', 
    [
        auth, 
        [
            check('title', 'Title is required')
                .not()
                .isEmpty(),
            check('company', 'Company is required')
                .not()
                .isEmpty(),
            check('from', 'From date is required')
                .not()
                .isEmpty()
        ]
    ],

async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array() });
        }


        const {
            title,
            company,
            location,
            from,
            to,
            current,
            description
        } = req.body;


        const newExp = {
            title,
            company,
            location,
            from,
            to,
            current,
            description
        }

        //const experience = [];

        try{
            const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

            profile.experience.unshift(newExp);

            await profile.save();

            res.json(profile);

        } catch(err){
            console.error(err.message);
            res.status(500).send('server put exp error')
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check if the experience field exits in profile object.

Comment: how would i do that ? .. 

if (!experience) {return res.status(500).send('no exp')};

this returned experience is not defined

Comment: Okay just console.log the profile object, see what its returning.

Comment: i commented out the "profile.experience.unshift(newExp);" and wrote it after that,

it returns the users full profile (minus the exp fields)

Comment: Which means the experience property doesnt exists in the database. Make sure the experience field exists in the document or handle it if its missing.

Comment: your a genius! ...i spelt experience wrong in an earlier code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on the same course, my solution was to change the line

```
profile.experience.unshift(newExp);
```

to

```
profile.experiences.unshift(newExp);
```

This is how it was saved in the database.

Comment: check "experience" field in your model carefully